# A group of people who have birthdays in distinct months

Tags: probability

This question came about when I was with a group of 8 friends (i.e. 9 in total), and we realised we all had birthdays in distinct months - we tried to work out the probability of this happening. The 2 answers we came up with seemed either too remote or too common:

The probability that I have a birthday in any given month is $\frac{1}{12}$, and so the probability that all the other people have birthdays in a different month is $\frac{8}{11}$; adding these together and multiplying by the number of people:

$ (\frac{1}{12} + \frac{8}{11})^9 $

gives 0.15 - which seems too big (and I've realised can't be correct because it gives an impossible answer when the number of friends is >11)

The second way I thought it could be calculated was

$\frac{1}{12} * \frac{1}{11} * \frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{9} * \frac{1}{8} * \frac{1}{7} * \frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{5} * \frac{1}{4}$

but this gives 1.25e-8, which seems too small.

What's the correct way to calculate it?!

Answer (score 2):

*HINT*

*Choose* $9$ of the $12$ months to "fill" and *permute* the $9$ people to determine who is in which month.

Finally divide by $12^{9}$ which represents all possible ways

---

drhab has given a simple solution by directly multiplying probabilities.
I thought my hint would help you in boning up on combinations and permutations

My hint amounts to $\dfrac {\binom{12}99!}{12^{9}}$

Or you could, using permutations, write $\dfrac{_{12}P_9}{12^{9}}$

Comment: That might be a relevant hint if my probability was better than it is!

Answer (score 0):

Speak out one by one in which month your birthday falls.

The probability that $9$ distinct months will be mentioned is:$$\frac{12}{12}\times\frac{11}{12}\times\frac{10}{12}\times\cdots\times\frac5{12}\times\frac{4}{12}=\frac{12!}{3!12^{9}}$$

E.g. the factor $\frac{10}{12}$ denotes the probability that the month mentioned by the third persons will not be a month allready mentioned under the condition that the months that were allready mentioned are two distinct ones.

The first person will mention a month. Then the probability that the second person will mention a month that differs from the first one is $\frac{11}{12}$. Then - if both mentioned months are indeed distinct - the probability that the third person will mention a month different from both is $\frac{10}{12}$. Et cetera.